# How do I determine which button in a RadioBox is selected in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a RadioBox in my application (with two radio buttons inside of the box), and I need to determine which button is selected in the box. I've seen examples where the radio buttons are created individually, but nothing for when they're part of a RadioBox.

Here's the code for my RadioBox.

```
self.radIPAddressInfo = wx.RadioBox(choices=['Automatically Determined',
          'Manual'], id=wxID_FRAME1RADIPADDRESSINFO,
          label=u'IP Address Information', majorDimension=1,
          name=u'radIPAddressInfo', parent=self.panelMain, pos=wx.Point(728,
          80), size=wx.Size(288, 136), style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
    self.radIPAddressInfo.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX,
          self.OnRadIPAddressInfoRadiobox, id=wxID_FRAME1RADIPADDRESSINFO)
```

Would I use something like

```
if self.RadIPAddressInfo.GetValue()="Automatically Determined":
     do something
else
     do something else
```

Thanks, and have a great day:)
Patrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.RadioBox-class.html

```
print self.RadIPAddressInfo.GetStringSelection(self) #returns selected item string
```

or

```
print self.RadIPAddressInfo.GetSelection()  #returns selected index
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the self.RadIPAddressInfo.GetStringSelection to make it work.